# How to automatically start Kafka upon system startup in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka, init.d

Does Kafka have an official way (e.g. an init.d script) to start Kafka on system start up?

The only official method to start Kafka I have seen is:

```
nohup ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties > ~/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1 &
```

I have tried to use a `@reboot` task in `crontab -e` however it did not start Kafka. Some people have also written custom init.d

There are also custom init.d scripts available (e.g. [one](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/kafka-rpm/blob/master/SOURCES/kafka.init), [two](https://gist.github.com/superscott/a1c67871cdd54b0c8693), [three](https://github.com/deric/kafka-packaging/blob/master/conf/init.debian)) however they are all different and I am not familiar enough with init.d to understand which one, if any to implement.

How to start Kafka on system startup?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's how I configure Kafka to start automatically on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo su
cp -R ~/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1 /opt
ln -s /opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1 /opt/kafka
```

Copy the following init script to /etc/init.d/kafka:

```
DAEMON_PATH=/opt/kafka/
PATH=$PATH:$DAEMON_PATH/bin

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        # Start daemon.
        echo "Starting Zookeeper";
        nohup $DAEMON_PATH/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon /$DAEMON_PATH/config/zookeeper.properties 2> /dev/null && \
        echo "Starting Kafka";
        nohup $DAEMON_PATH/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /$DAEMON_PATH/config/server.properties 2> /dev/null
        ;;
  stop)
        # Stop daemons.
        echo "Shutting down Zookeeper";
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper.server' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          kill -9 $pid
        else
          echo "Zookeeper was not Running"
        fi
        echo "Shutting down Kafka";
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          kill -9 $pid
        else
          echo "Kafka was not Running"
        fi
        ;;
  restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 2
        $0 start
        ;;
  status)
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper.server' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          echo "Zookeeper is Running as PID: $pid"
        else
          echo "Zookeeper is not Running"
        fi
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          echo "Kafka is Running as PID: $pid"
        else
          echo "Kafka is not Running"
        fi
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Make the kafka service with these commands:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/kafka
update-rc.d kafka defaults
```

Now you should be able to start and stop the kafka service like this:

```
sudo service kafka start
sudo service kafka status
sudo service kafka stop
```

If you want to remove the Kafka service later, run `update-rc.d -f kafka remove`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'm looking to do just this. Although my version of Ubuntu and version of Kafka appear to be a little later and the machine I've been tasked to do this on doesn't appear to have the "kafkakafka_2.11-0.10.0.1" item in my home (~) directory. Is this meant just to be the Kafka install directory, wherever that is? Just double checking, since I didn't personally install Kafka here or stand up the server, but am just tasked with automating the Kafka on startup. I'm also relatively new to Unix. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's the directory you get after downloading and extracting the tgz file from https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Comment: Addendum to above answer: Unless `BEGIN INIT INFO` preamble is added to this script, the script is ignored by update-rc.d utility for creating symbolic links. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/877383/16-10-server-update-rc-d-not-creating-symlinks-for-vncserver

Comment: Ubuntu16.4 said: kafka.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/kafka: Exec format error

Comment: is it ok to start kafka immediately after zookeeper ? no need for delay ? or wait for zookeeper to accept connections ?

Comment: Should not that /etc/init.d/kafka script start with "#! /bin/sh" ?

Answer (score 13):

**Download Kafka**

```
cd /opt
sudo wget http://mirror.hosting90.cz/apache/kafka/2.5.0/kafka-2.5.0-src.tgz
sudo tar -zxvf kafka-2.5.0-src.tgz
sudo mv kafka-2.5.0-src kafka
sudo rm kafka-2.5.0-src.tgz
cd kafka
sudo ./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.11.12
```

**Install Zookeeper**

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service
```

**Edit zookeeper.service**

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Start Zookeeper**

```
sudo systemctl enable zookeeper.service

sudo systemctl start zookeeper.service

sudo systemctl status zookeeper.service
```

**active (running)**

**Install Kafka**

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service
```

**Edit kafka.service**

```
[Unit]
Requires=zookeeper.service
After=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties > /opt/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1'
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Start Kafka**

```
sudo systemctl enable kafka.service

sudo systemctl start kafka.service

sudo systemctl status kafka.service
```

**active (running)**

**Test Kafka works**

**create topic**

```
sudo bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test-topic
```

**put messages to topic**

```
sudo bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic  
> test message1
> test messate2
^C
```

**read messages from topic**

```
sudo bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic test-topic
test message1
test messate2
^C
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I cant get the kafka service to boot properly after a reboot. Trying to get this working on a Raspberry Pi 4. Error is: `ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 192.168.1.150:9092: Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: setting: `TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure` sorted it, cheers.

Comment: topic creation command changed to `sudo ./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic test-topic`

Comment: Now that there is a `-daemon` flag for both the zookeeper and kafka start scripts, this could use an update.

Answer (score 8):

One easy approach is to use systemd. You should note that at the startup the environment variables like *JAVA_HOME* are not loaded yet, so we should introduce them to the system. One good solution is to create a file named `profile` and add all the necessary variable to that:

```
# /home/kafka/profile
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk8
KAFKA_HOME=/opt/kafka
```

Supposing you've installed Kafka on the path `/opt/kafka`, in order to Kafka run automatically after Ubuntu startup (tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and centOS7 and I guess it works on any distribution with the support of the systemd) do the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service  # open file to add service informations
```

Now add the following contents to the file

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka Daemon
Wants=syslog.target

# suppose you have a service named zookeeper that it start zookeeper and we want Kafka service run after the zookeeper service
After=zookeeper.service

[Service]    
Type=forking

# the user whom you want run the Kafka start and stop command under
User=kafka    

# the file path that contains envirnment variables
EnvironmentFile=/home/kafka/profile

# the directory that the commands will run there   
WorkingDirectory=/home/kafka/ 

# Kafka server start command
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /opt/kafka/config/server.properties

# Kafka server stop command
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh -daemon

TimeoutSec=30
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Note:** As Kafka need the zookeeper to connect it at the starting time, I supposed we have a zookeeper service too and I set the Kafka service to run after zookeeper service starting.

Now after saving the `kafka.service` file, just run the following command to create a link of the Kafka service and it will start every time you reboot the OS:

```
sudo systemctl enable kafka
```

Now you can start the Kafka service using the command:

```
sudo systemctl start kafka.service
```

and check the status of the service:

```
sudo systemctl status kafka.service
```