# how to start multiple redis service on ubuntu with redis.conf

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I have installed redis on ubuntu, in its working nicely.

then i need to make multiple service run on same machine, some of them master, and another slave.

i then make several redis.conf, with different port assigned and run it with

`sudo /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf`

`sudo /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redisSlave.conf`

`sudo /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redisSlave2.conf`

everything work fine, i can even start a sentinel and it work like a charm

then i want to auto start them on startup, i already do the same with kafka [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512287/how-to-automatically-start-kafka-upon-system-startup-in-ubuntu) with step that Jakub Krhovják explained.

there we make a service file, and do `sudo systemctl enable redis-slave.service`

here is my redis-slave.service

```
Unit]
Requires=redis-server.service
After=redis-server.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redisSlave.conf
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then i try to restart my vm, but when i check it with `sudo systemctl status redis-slave.service` i got

[image: systemctl status]

when i check it with `$ss -nlt` i cant find port that should be running. i even do `sudo systemctl start redis-slave.service`, and got same status when check it.

is there anything wrong with may redis-slave.service

Answer (score 0):

i have to change my redis-slave.service to make it works

```
[Unit]
Description=redis resque 6380
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redisSlave.conf --supervised systemd
ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-cli -h 192.168.56.101 -p 6380 shutdown

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

i found it from [here](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Installation/Configuring_OutSystems_with_Redis_in-memory_session_storage/Set_up_a_Redis_Cluster_for_Production_environments), the article is explaining about how to make redis cluster, great to read.